# Android error Unable to add window in onResume(), after binding failed in onCreate()

Tags: android

I know there are many questions and solutions for this error message.

But my problem is little different.

In my Activity `onCreate()` method i am doing a `bindservice()`.

Binding didn't happen i got log as

> "Binding with unknown activity: Token"

My `onResume` method is as below

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onResume() in");
    // Status bar
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS );

    super.onResume();
}
```

After the line `Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onResume() in");` in `onResume()` i am getting below error,

> "Attempted to add application window with unknown token Token.
>   Aborting."
>
> AndroidRuntime: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable
>   to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@is not valid; is your
>   activity running?

I searched on Internet they say this issue comes when we use wrong context. But i dont think so that is the problem in my case.

Also this issue was reproduced only once till now.

Comment: @Kristiyan Varbanov - Any idea about the root cause of issue.

Comment: i made a research too for your problem but unsuccessful ..